# Htaccess Mod Rewrite: allow integers or a specific word

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess to tunnel traffic to my index.php. Below is one of the lines I am using:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]*)$ /index.php?&page=$1
```

What I want is to allow only numeric values, **and the word 'all'**. So the regexp should match:

- page/1
- page/15
- page/all

How can matching against both values be acchieved? A simple solution would be ([0-9al]*), but that isn't perfect as it also allows for values like 'al9', 'lalalala' etc. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer according to: `is it possible to disallow '0' as an accepted value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[0-9]*` also matches zero numbers, you have to use + instead of *

To add 'all', use the pipe:

```
 RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+|all)$ /index.php?&page=$1
```

disallow '0':

```
 RewriteRule ^page/([1-9]{1}[0-9]*|all)$ /index.php?&page=$1
```

`[1-9]{1}[0-9]*` means:

- one number 1 to 9, followed by a uncertain occurrences (0, 1,...,unlimited) of the other numbers, even 0
- so it matches a single number (besides 0) OR
- 10, 11, 12, ..., 20, 21, ..., 23456

Comment: Thanks! Something else, is it possible to disallow '0' as an accepted value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^page/((?!0+$)[0-9]+|all)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will also avoid rewriting `/page/0` `/page/00` etc